# Why does (x)->fn(x) give a different answer to fn in a lodash map expression?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, lodash

I'm using Lodash...

```
coffee> _ = require("lodash")
[stuff deleted]
```

This expression gives the right answer...

```
coffee> _.map("7-9".split("-"), (x)->parseInt(x))
[ 7, 9 ]
```

But this one gives something slightly different for the last result in the array:

```
coffee> _.map("7-9".split("-"), parseInt)
[ 7, NaN ]
coffee>
```

Why are the answers different? Surely **(x)->paresInt(x)** should behave the same as **parseInt**

Comment: Check what parameters are passed to the `_.map` function callback. Then check what parameters `parseInt` accepts. Hint: there are more than one. Hint 2: the actual code to run is `(a, b, c) -> parseInt(a, b, c)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

`require('lodash').map("7-9".split("-"), Number)`

;)

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
that means parseInt called with two arguments, second, which must be the radix, now is 1 (parseInt(9, 1))

Also you can use
https://lodash.com/docs#ary

`_.map("7-9".split("-"), _.ary(parseInt, 1));`